# Gradient and hessian of $\log(1+x^TAx)$

Tags: derivatives, matrix-calculus, hessian-matrix, scalar-fields

I want to find Gradient and hessian of $log(1+x^TAx)$ where $A$ is positive semi definite.

My attempt: $\nabla = x^T(A+A^T)/1+x^TAx$

Hessian = $(A+A^T)(1+x^TAx)-(x^T(A+A^T))^Tx^T(A+A^T)/(1+x^TAx)^2$

Is that correct?

Comment: the last numerator cannot be computed due to a dimension mismatch

Comment: @LinAlg thanks! Edited, is that correct now?

Comment: seems like it, but if you are unsure you can always check the answer numerically

Comment: You could use more parentheses.

Comment: Sounds correct to me.....

Comment: You need parentheses in the denominator of the gradient and a division in the first term of the Hessian: $$\eqalign{g&=\frac{(A^T+A)x}{1+x^TAx}\cr H&=\frac{A^T+A}{1+x^TAx}-gg^T}$$